# brown's irobot_create_2_1 driver unable to run

Tags: ros, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ rosrun irobot_create_2_1 driver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/bin/driver.py", line 15, in 
from irobot_create_2_1.msg import SensorPacket
ImportError: No module named irobot_create_2_1.msg

Running Ubuntu 11.10 (fresh install).
Installed ROS using: sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop
Installed irobot_create_2_1 using: sudo apt-get install ros-electric-brown-drivers

I thought that was all I needed to do to get it working... or is there something extra?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12453/brown%27s-irobot_create_2_1-driver-unable-to-run/) by [nsstrunks](https://answers.ros.org/users/1572/nsstrunks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-12-25**:
If you're looking for a driver for the irobot create.  I suggest that you look at the turtlebot_driver package and turtlebot_node.  The turtlebot is based on the iRobot Create.  http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_driver  and http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Michael Ferguson (fergs) is right. I accidentally pulled both the Makefile and rosdep.yaml from the irobot_create_2_1 repo when doing some other maintenance work. This has been corrected both in the repo and in our package releases (though these of course take time to catch up). You can pull a fresh checkout via:

```
svn co https://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/irobot_create_2_1 irobot_create_2_1
```

or you can download the individually missing files: [Makefile](http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/irobot_create_2_1/Makefile) and [rosdep.yaml](http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/irobot_create_2_1/rosdep.yaml) .

My sincere apologies. This was really bone-headed and I will spend the requisite time on the wheel.

_Trevor

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2011-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that the package is not building, there is no "Makefile" and so messages are not being generated. I would suggest filing a ticket with the brown maintainers.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-12-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1